# How to resolved 'if' unmatched error on running ksh script?

Tags: linux, shell, ksh

I am new to scripting and using linux. The below script that I have written simply prints the passed arguments and does a check in if condition. But not sure why I keep getting 'if' unmatched error

```
echo "The number of arguments passed "
echo $#;
echo "The passed arguments are "
echo $@

count="$#"

echo "Count is "
echo $count;

if [[ $count -eq "2" ]]; then
   echo "Correct";
else
   echo "Incorrect";
fi

when I run script above as

$ ./MyScript "ABC" "XYZ"
```

Output ->

```
The number of arguments passed
: not found [No such file or directory]
2
The passed arguments are
: not found [No such file or directory]
ABC XYZ
: not found [No such file or directory]
Count is 
: not found [No such file or directory]
2
syntax error 'if' unmatched
```

Comment: How are you running the file?

Comment: Does your file have incorrect line endings (msdos crlf)?  It should only have unix style line endings (lf). Check the file with a different editor (example vi).